# Infinite scrolling component in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using a Data Table (p-Table) component from PrimeNG, but it seems it doesn't support infinite scrolling. Is there any existing grid/table component which support infinite scrolling? I am trying not to create my own if there is already existing one out there.

Many thanks!

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG now supports infinite scroll (aka "virtual scroll") as shown in their showcase: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable/scroll.

It was buggy until now, but it seems the release 4.2 fixes the main issues with it (though I didn't personally tested it yet).

See https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/milestone/73?closed=1.